# Installation problems with DS Bulk loader on Ubuntu

Tags: python, csv, cassandra, bulkloader, dse

I'm trying to install the DS Bulk Loader as reported here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/install/dsbulkInstall.html

but that's the problem:

I follow the procedure but I don't know how follow the part about "Java executable is required".

So, cause it is the first time that I'll do an executable in JAVA...I have to copy as shown points 1, 2., 3., on a .jar?

and what's about the part about #Remote JMX configuration into the link?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is basically saying that you must have Java installed on the operating system, for DSE currently, this would be recommended to be Java 8. (Either OpenJDK or Oracle).

If you are just performing a single load / export, then the JMX is not necessarily of relevance, that is for monitoring purposes.

Comment: dear @andrew so are you sayng that is enough what II have done before the session that regards JAVA? I have java...but....ds bulkloader don't start if on my terminal I write, for example, dsbulk --version says that command not found

Comment: is the location of dsbulk within your path? if not you would have to add it, or run the command from within the dsbulk folder.

Comment: to be much more clear...i followed this steps:1. used the "curl" command on nal to download DSbulk 2. used the command to unpack the donload with tar.....then Should I use dsbulk --help to verify the Istallation on termina? Because If it is as I have done, the terminal says that the command is not found...so...I tried also to export dsbulk_java_opts and then the procedure to invoke dsbulk but at the same nothing. Is it necessary to install all datastax, at this point? About this I don't think so. The problem remain around the call of dsbulk

Comment: I suspect you do not have the dsbulk/bin folder in your path, cd into dsbulk-1.6.0/bin or whichever version you have.

Comment: solved on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64682683/datastax-bulk-loader-1-7-0-for-apache-cassandra-installation-doesnt-work-on-ubu/64683498?noredirect=1#comment114373481_64683498   @andrew