# DataStax Bulk Loader 1.7.0 for Apache Cassandra installation doesn't work on Ubuntu

Tags: java, csv, ubuntu, cassandra, datastax

maybe this could be very helpful to other people.

This is the link in which is explained the installatif DSbulk loader.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/install/dsbulkInstall.html

Someone could explain step by step the procedure to install it?

The first part in the link is very clear, but if you have installed JAVA (as in my case) when on terminal you run " dsbulk --version  " it says "command not found".

I hope this will be very helpful, there are no tutorials neither on youtube.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run it this way, then you need to put the `bin` directory of the DSBulk distribution into the shell's `PATH`.  If you're staying in the top directory of DSBulk, then you can do following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)/bin
```

and then you can call it as `dsbulk`.  Another alternatives are to call it as `bin/dsbulk`, or `full_path/bin/dsbulk`

Comment: dear @alex ott  ok....but now i it saay that "Unable to finhav 8 (or later) execle. Check _HOME and PATH envirnoment variables" ..How can I solve this?

Comment: what version of Java do you have? Is it in the `PATH` as well?

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_272" d when I wrote "echo $PATH" it gives "jdk-install-dir/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"

Comment: You need to have full path to java

Comment: when I do "echo $JAVA_HOME" it gives "jdk-install-dir"

Comment: It should be also complete path, like, /usr/lib/jvm/...

Comment: It doesn't appear....maybe I'll try an hard solution, I'ill reinstall ubuntu and then all installations...I'll post here the evolution of the situation

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all! Problem solved!

Many times it happens that it must be set the right path to use java...so you need to follow this link (very useful):

https://vitux.com/how-to-setup-java_home-path-in-ubuntu/

Then on terminal:

```
$ export PATH=path-to-unpacked-location/dsbulk-1.7.0/bin:$PATH

$ source ~/.bashrc

$ dsbulk --version
```

please don't copy $ when you want to insert code into the terminal! XD

and! That's it!